# RFC: License for a prospective sandbox viewer

Tags: discussion, sandbox, user-interface

## TL;DR

I'm trying to figure out what license is best to use with a proposed CodeGolf.SE sandbox viewer. Please read the whole question/proposal before answering.

---

## Main Question

What would be the best license for a proposed sandbox viewer? I would maintain it as an open-source project, and I wanted to know of the best license to use for it.

## Disclaimer

Before everyone who disagrees goes on a rant, read this:

- If you want it to, this will keep track of the sandbox length and create a new one if it gets above a certain length.

  - It can't mark new sandboxes as featured unless someone with adequate permissions either enables support or does it manually.
- Using this web app will be optional: the questions can still be proposed/commented/answered as normal on Meta.

## Features/Details

- Completely from the site
- A single-page HTML/CSS/JS application, runnable from anywhere, even locally.
- Allows for viewing, asking, commenting, or (on some) answering proposed questions.
- Uses a hard-coded sandbox question on the Meta site to hold all its data
- Presents it in a more convenient fashion than the question itself
- Data is also human readable in questions
- Require Stack Exchange's OpenID login to propose/edit/comment on questions
- Allows embedding potential answers or answer-like comments in the questions themselves given permission by the proposed question's asker.

  - Makes it a community wiki to enable this
  - Reads the history to get the user's comment
- Comments to the proposed question go in comments section
- Comments to proposed answers/answer-like comments would go under the answer itself
- Proposed questions are created as answers to the Meta sandbox
- When ready, a user is prompted for any changes, then a new question is created on the main site

  - Old is automatically changed to a link to the question, clearly marked as posted and with all extra content removed

## Nits

1. It would embed a tiny bit of metadata via HTML comments in the body to tell if some question is already posted on the main site (falls back on a regex) so it can hide the question.
2. Pieces of it may be turned into code challenges (many JS-specific) here on the main site, with licensing restrictions to override the stock CC-BY-SA license, and then used in developing the app.

## Extras

If there are any features you want/don't want, please let me know.

I would be the maintainer of this project (working on beginnings now), but I know I will get some help from the community in developing this application. So, I'm looking to you all for input on what license to use for it.

Also, I (or another contributor) will make a PSA when it is ready for testing.

This idea came up in chat as a potential solution to the sandbox problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with licensing restrictions to override the stock CC-BY-SA license". Anything posted as questions or answers on Stack Exchange are required to be licensed under CC BY-SA; you can add other licences too, but you cannot take away the CC BY-SA.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need metadata to mark username on answers or comments; that's what the post history is for. Otherwise, it's easy for a miscreant to falsify such information by editing the post outside of your app.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Okay.

Comment: I would suggest the [AGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html), since it is specifically for web apps.

Comment: The christopher license. IF YOU USE DIS U MUST GIVE CREDIT TO ME ON THE PLACE YOU USE THIS

Comment: All caps are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, there is *nothing* special about this from a licensing point of view.
(But I am not a lawyer and I am not your lawyer).

You always have the rights to relicensis your works to yourself, so you can use that to make code-challenges from it.

You are basically free to use what ever license you want.

I personally suggest MIT.
It is common,
it is simple,
it is permissive.