# A simple userscript for collapsing sandbox answers

Tags: discussion, sandbox, userscript

## Description

As it appears [the sandbox on meta is here to stay](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2011/3808), I've written a very simple userscript that will allow you to collapse sandbox answers to reduce clutter. (This may be able to be replaced when the [fancy sandbox viewer thingy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2021/3808) is finished, but for now it'll make navigating the sandbox a little easier.)

## Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

## Code

`stackexchange-codegolf-sandbox-collapse.user.js`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name stackexchange-codegolf-sandbox-collapse
// @namespace http://keyboardfire.com/
// @license MIT
// @description A simple userscript for collapsing sandbox answers
// @version 1.0.0
// @match *://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

if ($('#question-header a').text().indexOf('Proposed Question Sandbox') > -1) {
    $('.answer').each(function() {
        var ans = $(this);
        var ansPosted = $('.post-text', ans).children().length === 1;
        var btnMessage = '(' + (ansPosted ? 'challenge posted; ' : '') + 'click to toggle view)';
        $('table', ans).wrap($('<div>').addClass('posted-challenge').css('display', ansPosted ? 'none' : ''));
        ans.prepend($('<input>').attr('type', 'button').css('margin-bottom', '20px').val(btnMessage).click(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.posted-challenge').toggle('slow');
        }));
    });
}
```

## Issues

- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned): Show title, tags (if included), and votes even when collapsed

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

If I click on the "show *N* more comments" link, comments do not show up with the userscript enabled.

[image: Sandbox comments with userscript enabled]